# I'm getting duplicate rows when using Datatables plugin Jquery(driving me nuts!!!)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to display some data from a list sharepoint and then using jquery Datatable plugin to  show the  data.
I'm very sure its returning 2 rows but for some reason i keep getting a third row.
Is there any reson why jquery Datatable plugin returning another row...
I'm going crazy..
** Sent it to a div and it has only 2 rowa
See below

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <<th>Title</th>
                        <th>Contact Number</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                         <th>Date Due</th>
                         <th>Location</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <<th>Title</th>
                        <th>Contact Number</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                         <th>Date Due</th>
                         <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>


</table>


  var data ='';


            $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() { 



            var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
            var store = $(this).attr("ows_Location");
            var Reason = $(this).attr("ows_Reason");
            var Status = $(this).attr("ows_Status");
            var contactnumber = $(this).attr("ows_Contact_x0020_Number");
            var datedue = $(this).attr("ows_Date_x0020_Due");


           data += "<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + contactnumber + "</td><td>" + Reason + "</td><td>" + Status + "</td><td>" + datedue + "</td><td>" + store + "</td></tr>"; 


     });

 $("#example tbody").append(data);
$('#example').dataTable(
    {
     /*"bFilter": true,
     "bPaginate": true,
     "bSort": true*/
     /*"bJQueryUI": true,*/
     /*"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"*/
    }
    );
```

Comment: Your initialisation generally looks okay, but could you run your table through the DataTables debugger ( http://debug.datatables.net ) so we can see what the table state looks like? Also what does Firebug say your returned JSON is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first row defined by `<thead>`

Your second row defined by `<tbody>` and it contains the actual data

Your third row defined by `<tfoot>`     **<-- this is the "third" row that you want to get rid of ?**

also you got typo twice in your `<<th>Title` remove one redundant `<`